# What control is this? - C# - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am currently starting to program a downloader for a website, I've been looking at downloaders to find out how I should format multiple downloads and I have decide on a table.

But I don't know the name of the control in C# (look at image below).

As seen below: [image: here]

The red box is the control, I want to use in C#.

I've tried looking at a DataTable but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: It can be any control. You can write unlimited controls after all

Comment: Looks like a `ListView` in details mode, along with owner drawing for the progress bar. Or a WPF `DataGrid`, as Needham suggests.

Comment: Also, it can be a Windows Forms `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a `datagrid`, however that looks like it was made with WPF not winforms

Comment: How would I make it then?

Comment: You will need to make it in WPF then use XAML to databind the progress bar

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

It may very well be a custom control, so it's nothing that you'd find out of the box.

That said, you can use the `Spy++` tool in the Windows SDK to inspect running applications to determine things like this.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx

Comment: Use the `Find` feature which will let you mouse over it.

Answer (score 0):

For Win Forms use the datagridview from the tools bar and create a custom column for the progress bar.